# How do I practice Pyro rocket reflect with non-standard rocket launchers?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

There are training maps out there that can be used to practice rocket reflect timing.  However, training maps spawn soldier bots using the default loadout.  The standard rocket launcher is probably the easiest to reflect, but I almost never deflect the Direct Hit and Liberty Launcher successfully because I am not used to the timing and have no way to practice except when I run across soldiers using them in a public server.  Is there any way to practice single-player against those weapons with bots?

Comment: I'd love to know this as well. The Liberty Launcher is the bane of my existence (Direct Hit is OK).

Comment: Based on the [Bot Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots) it doesn't look like it is possible to modify a bot's loadout. So looks like the only way is by asking another player.

Comment: Maybe you could edit an MvM `.pop` file to have a bunch of enemies with specific weapons as the only wave. That would probably be a hassle to use though.

Answer (score 2):

The only way bots can have non-stock weapons is in Mann vs. Machine. Luckily, it's not terribly hard to edit and customize MVM waves. Check out [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2884318) to learn more about creating and editing waves, and [this guy's Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/TF2-MvM-Wave-Generator/358897087523528) for a download link to a jar file that creates MVM wave files for you.

As for specific wave settings, I would recommend sending an individual soldier once every 10 seconds or so, alternating rocket launcher types. You could also even mix it up with with huntsman snipers and flare gun pyros.